# I want to code in MVC razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want the below functionality in MVC razor.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Delete" onclick="Button1_Click"  OnClientClick="CheckDelete()"/>
```

I used

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Action", "Controller", new { onClientclick = "checkDelete();" }, null)
```

But this is not working.

Comment: What is not working? What is actually happening?

Comment: And inspect the html that your generating - `new { onClientclick = "checkDelete();" }` is adding a route value, not a html attribute. You need to remove the last (`null`) parameter from `@Html.ActionLink()`

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Action", "Controller", new { onClientclick = "checkDelete();" }, null)

Comment: Read my first comment - your question need to explain what is not working! _But this is not working._ is not acceptable

Comment: use this - @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Action", "Controller", null, new { onclick = "checkDelete();" })

Comment: Actually @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Action", "Controller", new { id=id,onClientclick = "checkDelete();" }, null) ... I am sending the parameter to the controller, do if null is not there, id will be sent as html attribute and not as route value. I want id to be added as route value and onclick as html attribute. Is that possibe?

Comment: you want id to be sent as routeparamter?

Comment: yup and onclick as html attribute

Comment: tell us what you are getting now...

Answer (score 3):

`OnClientClick` is an attribute for `runat="server"` elements where `OnClick` is reserved for serverside events.

The `ActionLink` HTML helper accepts a collection of HTML attributes, and does not have this concern with server `OnClick` events, so you're supposed to pass `onclick` (if you don't want to bind the event externally)

Comment: Actually @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Action", "Controller", new { id=id,onClientclick = "checkDelete();" }, null) ... I am sending the parameter to the controller, so if null is not there, id will be sent as html attribute and not as route value. I want id to be added as route value and onclick as html attribute. Is that possibe?

Comment: @Raj : please understand that you simply cant use onClientClick as is it not a html property...secondly if you want the id to be going in the routing you can create the url accordingly at the first place, and another thing, in the webforms code, you are using a button and in mvc a actionlink....any specific reasons?

Answer (score 1):

HtmlAttributes can be specified in the 5th parameter. So, You need to use the below way:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Action", "Controller", new {id=yourid}, new { onclick = "return checkDelete();" })
```

Note-You need to use onclick attribute. Since MVC doesn't support server controls, you can't use server side events

Comment: Actually @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Action", "Controller", new { id=id,onClientclick = "checkDelete();" }, null) ... I am sending the parameter to the controller, so if null is not there, id will be sent as html attribute and not as route value. I want id to be added as route value and onclick as html attribute. Is that possibe?

Comment: have updated my answer. you have to add return keyword and add id as mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You cant trigger Action & onclick at a time. So do your code in Action Method using this

```
 @Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { Parameter = Parameter })
```

Comment: Actually @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Action", "Controller", new { id=id,onClientclick = "checkDelete();" }, null) ... I am sending the parameter to the controller, do if null is not there, id will be sent as html attribute and not as route value. I want id to be added as route value and onclick as html attribute. Is that possibe?

Comment: explain me the scenario. Need more clarity on this. Why you are using both Action & onclick? What is the need?

Comment: onclick- when click on button, using js i need to show an alert message. if this alert message return true... i need to call an Action in the contrioller